# Is it enough to find the recurrence relation or should I prove by induction?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, recurrence-relations, proof-explanation

The question is given below:

> [image]

**My question is:**

I have calculated the determinant for $n=3$ and $n=4$ and I can guess that we have the following recurrence relation $$\det (A_{n}) = \det (A_{n-1}) - \det (A_{n-2})$$, but the question said show that, so how can I prove this recurrence relation?

**In general: My question is how to prove this recurrence relation?**

**EDIT:**

Also, I think the statement of the question is wrong as it is also $-1$ in case of $n =4$.

Comment: @saulspatz the statement is not true

Comment: Please avoid posting images with a problem statement, edit the question and write down the statement. This is important for future usability of the questions on this website.

Comment: You can prove the recurrence relation by using the Laplace expansion of the determinant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove the relationship you can simply multiply out the determinant.

For $n\ge3$, $\det (A_{n}) = a_{11}\det (A_{n-1})-a_{12}a_{21}\det (A_{n-2})$

Therefore

$\det (A_{n}) = \det (A_{n-1}) - \det (A_{n-2})$.

$\det (A_{n})$ is then $0$ if $n=3k+2$ and is $(-1)^{k}$ if $n=3k$ or $n=3k+1.$

**Proof using induction**

Assume the result to be true for all values smaller than $n$. We know the result is true for $n=1,2,3$.

There are six cases. First suppose $n=6k+1$.

$\det (A_{6k+1}) = \det (A_{6k}) - \det (A_{6k-1})=1-0=1$.

Next suppose $n=6k+2$.

$\det (A_{6k+2}) = \det (A_{6k+1}) - \det (A_{6k})=$ etc.

You obtain 6 results all of which will be in agreement with our stated result. This might look involved but all we are doing is proving that the sequence of determinants is 1,0,-1,-1,0,1,1,0,-1,-1,0, 1, 1, ...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100389/discussion-on-answer-by-s-dolan-is-it-enough-to-find-the-recurrence-relation-or).

Answer (score 1):

Take a matrix of an unspecified dimension $n$ and develop the determinant along the first row.
It demonstrates, as in the other answer, that your recurrence is exact.

However the starting conditions are  $D_1 = 1,\; D_2 = 0$, so the complete recurrence is
$$
D_{\,n}  = D_{\,n - 1}  - D_{\,n - 2}  + \left[ {n = 1} \right] - \left[ {n = 2} \right]
$$
where $[P]$ denotes the [*Iverson bracket*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)
$$
\left[ P \right] = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 & {P = TRUE}  \\
   0 & {P = FALSE}  \\
 \end{array} } \right.
$$

The result so is
$$
D_{\,n}  = \left\{ {\matrix{
   {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} } & {n = 3k + 1}  \cr 
   0 & {n = 3k + 2}  \cr 
   { - \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} } & {n = 3k + 3}  \cr 
 } } \right.\quad \left| {\;0 \le k} \right.
$$
or
$$
D_{\,n + 1}  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,\left\lfloor {n/3} \right\rfloor } \left\{ {\matrix{
   1 & {n \equiv 0\;\;\left( {\bmod 3} \right)}  \cr 
   0 & {n \equiv 1\;\;\left( {\bmod 3} \right)}  \cr 
   { - 1} & {n \equiv 2\;\;\left( {\bmod 3} \right)}  \cr 
 } } \right.\quad \left| {\;0 \le n} \right.
$$